# how to use like with findBy in symfony3?

Tags: symfony

I am using symfony3:
I want use like in my query.

```
 $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:ABC'); 
       echo $searchstring = "LIKE '%".$searchtxt."%'"; die;
       $res=$repository->findBy(array('fname' => $searchstring));          
       $normalizer = new ObjectNormalizer();      
       $encoder = new JsonEncoder();
       $serializer = new Serializer(array($normalizer), array($encoder));
       $response=$serializer->serialize($res, 'json'); // Output: {"name":"foo","sportsman":false}
       return new Response($response);
```

Its return **null**

Anyone can suggest me ?

Answer (score 2):

The `find*()` methods of Doctrine repositories don't allow to perform queries using `LIKE` for comparison. You need to write a custom DQL query (see [Querying for Objects with DQL](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#querying-for-objects-with-dql) and [Doctrine Query Language](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html)):

```
$query = $em->createQuery("SELECT abc FROM AppBundle:ABC abc WHERE fname LIKE :fname");
$query->setParameter('fname', 'LIKE "%'.$searchtxt.'%"');
$result = $query->getResult();
```